# How to hide two div with the same name but in different location without knowingt the div name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a perl script that will create a html report with two rows(one on the right and one on the left). The perl script will create multiple div with a name of block[#] example, block1, block2,block3 all depends of how many section the rows have. Each row will have block1, block2, etc..

so when I hit let say the a h3 title om that section will hide example block1 on both rows. I'm new with Jquery, so I have look around and I have not found a solution for this. I have this jquery, but it is static. Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("h3").click(function () {
         $(".block").toggle();
     });
 });
```

I can't really post the html code because, I will be violating company policy, but I will put the tags:

```
<div class="file_wrapper">
    <h2>Previous Version of Pre.report.txt</h2>




    <div class="file_inner">
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block0">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block1">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block2">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="file_wrapper">
    <h2>New Version of Post.report.txt</h2>
    <div class="file_inner">
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block0">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block1">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%" class="block2">
            <h3> Title </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html as well.

Comment: The output html so we can see what your perl script produces.

Comment: Put unique `id` on each `div` and then refer to them that way. What do you mean by *"same name"*, do you mean *"same class"*?

Comment: I think you're saying each header will have two blocks with a class name of 'block'. You could just target the first one or the second one specifically using `$(this).find('.block').eq(1)` to get just the second one. http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't see a single element with the class name `block`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make sure the two divs(that contain the block#'s) have similar structures.

Then you can try something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/LZ99t/2/)

```
var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
$('.'+parentClass).hide();
```

Edit: This fixes the problem pointed out by Metagrapher. Keep in mind though, this is not the best way of doing it, you'd be better off giving your blocks custom attributes to prevent any confusion(duplicating their id's would do the trick, but I wouldn't recommend it. Not really a 'good practice')

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/LZ99t/3/)

Comment: Naturally, this code only works if there is only a single class on the parent element, as the class attribute will contain spaces if there are multiple classes. http://jsfiddle.net/48pp9/1/

Comment: @Metagrapher Yeah, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed now.

Comment: Is there any way to hide the content and not hide <H3>, so I can hide and show content.

Comment: Try `$('.' + parentClass).find('*:not(h3)')` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/LZ99t/5/)

Answer (score 1):

May be tomething like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h3").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".shared-parent").find(".block").toggle();
    });
});
```

It will work if "h3" element have shared parent (".shared-parent") with ".block" element, what we have to toggle