# How to show and hide two unique sections with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an script that will create a html that will have two columns and each columns have different sections. The amount of section is unknown so it can be section 1, section 2, section 3 (section is just a placeholder for the title). I have did some research and I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614849/how-to-hide-two-div-with-the-same-name-but-in-different-location-without-knowing?noredirect=1#comment30850630_20614849) question. This is similar what I want, but I want to use it with the following styles: 
[my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xx6kA/)
I would like the accordion work on the same section on both column.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
  </head>

 <body>
                            <div>
                              <!-- introduce objective of page -->
                              <header>

                              </header>
      <div class="file_wrapper">
        <div class="file_inner">

<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3><div>
<span class="diff"><p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p></span>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<span class="diff"><p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3><div>
<span class="minus"><p>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3><div>
<p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </div>                </div>                                                                                                    
              </div>
              </div>

      <div class="file_wrapper">

        <div class="file_inner">
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3><div>
<span class="diff"><p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p></span>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<span class="diff"><p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3><div>
<p>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3><div>
<span class="plus"><p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
  </span>
                </div>                                                                                                    
              </div>
              <script>


$(".file_inner").addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
  .find("h3")
    .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
    .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
    .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>')
    .click(function() {
      $(this)
        .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
        .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s").end()
        .next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").slideToggle();
      return false;
    })
    .next()
      .addClass("ui-accordion-content  ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
      .show();
</script>

          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It is working for me. What are you seeing that is not working?

Comment: This is a perfect example of how unreadable too much chaining can make your JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm new in jquery and html. I was just put on a project to make my script output on the web. I have to start some where.

Comment: @amb1s1 jsfidle.net is down for me right now, its my IPS nothing wrong from your side

Comment: @amb1s1 No worries, mate, sorry for putting you down. Let's see if we can give you some pointers for how to improve things. Did you write your script from scratch, or is it copied from somewhere?

Comment: My manager send me this link http://jsbin.com/eqape
of what the look that he wants. I don't know where he found it. I know how basic jquery works and basic html. I just edit it a little bit to make it work on my code, but not entirely.

Comment: That's [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). That should make your life easier!

Comment: I saw it before but that's not what I want. I want to be able to hide and show individual section and all section should be .show when the page load. Also, when I click hide on section 1 on the left or right column the other section 1 should hide and show at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery UI's accordion for this, here's an easy way to open both sections simultaneously:

http://codepen.io/neagle/pen/Bdhmb

var $accordions = $('.accordion');

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
  beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass('programatic')) {
      var active = $this.children('.ui-accordion-content').index(ui.newPanel);
      var $otherAccordions = $accordions.not($(this));

      $otherAccordions.addClass('programatic');
      $otherAccordions.accordion('option', 'active', active);
      $otherAccordions.removeClass('programatic');
    }
  }
});
```

If you prefer not to use jQuery UI, the strategy should be the same with whatever you want to try. When something is selected, find out its index within the column, then trigger activation of the other item with the same index in the other column.

Comment: Also, in your code can only show one section at a time. I would like to be able to do show section 1, section 2, section 3 and see all the section open. Thanks for your time

Comment: I didn't make an example that could be dropped in place on your code. I don't mean any offense, but your code is unworkably chained and nested - if I were to work on it, I'd need to start from scratch. But you should be able to figure out how to make it work based on my suggestion: when a section is opened, find out what its index is inside its parent column. Then find the item in the other column with the same index and programatically trigger it to open/close, too.

Comment: I understand, but I try your code on JSfiddle and it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: My code is actually on CodePen. If it's not working for you, I don't know what to tell you. :) It works fine on my end.

Comment: For some reason, JSFiddle is not working . I use my code on codepen and it is working. Still not the look that I'm looking. I might just pay somebody to do. I'm not a jquery guy and I'm not planning to be. Thanks